# Yii + Angular basic setup questions... inherited project

Tags: angularjs, yii, yii2, bower

I have just inherited a Yii + Angular project and have a few (very basic) questions.

The website makes use of the Yii framework and also Angular.js for much of the frontend operation. The entire site is comprised of multiple Yii apps and has the following hierarchy:

I have only expanded two of the folders-

api
assets
backend
common
console
**dist**
- css
- fonts
- images
- js
**frontend**
- app
- assets
- bower_components
- config
- controllers
- models
- node_modules
- runtime
- tests
- views
- web
- widgets
prerender
tests
vendor

Questions follow:

-- Assets
Assets for this app reside in a folder called "dist" located at the root level (seen above) and the Angular app resides in "frontend/app".

1. The "Assets" folder at the root level is empty, it never gets populated with anything and from reading the literature on Yii I would assume it would be populated with files as required by the site. Is it being overridden by "dist" and if so, which are the configuration files?
2. I would like to develop the website but making changes to any Angular code (i.e. controllers in javascript) are not reflected when I run the app locally. The website reads from a minified javascript file located in "dist/js" but how to get the framework to refresh this file after changes are made?

   - Configuration
     I know that the main Yii configuration settings can be found in index.php but what if the solution consists of multiple Yii apps (which it does?). There appears to be a settings file in each app location, if so, what purpose does the root index.php serve?

Any help, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the configuration files for each application in the related  application/config/*.php  .. so in you case you should have

```
/backend/config

/frontend/config
```

common part are in

```
common/config
```

for local / remote configuration difference .. the config files are divided  by

```
 main-local
 main 
 param-local
 param
```

you could do somthing similar for dist .. with a dist/yourfile-local ..  and you different asset loading for remote and local  ..